# Save datastream received as unit8array as pdf to filesystem on the front end

Tags: javascript, pdf, electron, data-uri

```
const reader = response.body.getReader();
        reader.read()
            .then(({ done, value }) => {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                value = window.btoa(value) //<-tried with and without
                link.download = "test.pdf";
                link.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+value
                link.click();
                // console.log(window.atob(value))
            })
```

this just saves a pdf file which has nothing in it /  is unreadable.

value in the callback is unicode for a pdf file read into a data stram so its just a bunch of numbers in a unit8array. I tried converting it to base64 and downloading that through a data uri but haven't had any luck.

This is in an electron application btw

edit:

When I receive the data from the backend, the request shows it as unicode, but the response gives it to me as a readable stream. I am 100% sure I would be able to parse the unicode and save a PDF file from it but I do not know how to get the unicode form from the given readable stream.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the file a name:

```
link.name = "file.pdf";
```

and then using the base64 to make a data URI. If that doesn't work, try making your data URI like this:

```
'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,' + value;
```

It might be worthwhile to debug the dataURI if possible, the data you're getting could be corrupted to begin with which will have you chasing your tail.

You could also try converting the Uint8Array to a File object:

```
var arr = [];
var arr.push(value);
var pdf = new File(arr, 'test.pdf', {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

And then attach that to a FormData object and post it to your server. Edit* oops didn't see you were doing this with electron so I'm not sure if the above applies but it may still be helpful. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the help,
Sadly this didn't make a difference, I still get an empty file when I try to open the pdf. What's weird is that the error is "File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported", when I specify it as an application/pdf in the data uri

Comment: Can you show me the full data URI? Also have you tried manually adding ".pdf" to the name of the downloaded file? Sounds dumb but it's worth a shot

Comment: Im actually not 100% sure I can because of possible (very encoded) sensitive information; but I can say decoding the base64 gives me the original data stream (ie: 34,12,23,4,65,43 etc) But I would think that I would want to get the unicode wouldn't I? This is my first time dealing with this sort of thing so I'm sorry if I am misled somewhere.

Also, adding .pdf didn't change anything as it was already there because of link.download ="test.pdf"

Comment: To be more clear. In the response tab in chrome data tools from my GET req, I see Unicode for a PDF file. 


In my Promise , I get it as a readable stream which is just a huge array of numbers 


Should I be trying to get the Unicode to put into the URI instead of the readable stream? If so how do I do this...

Comment: No the base64 is definitely what you want, that looks like it should be working. Try playing around with the mime-type, use the data URI prefix I posted above if you haven't already. Have you tried just copy pasting the data URI into your browser? You should be able to see the valid PDF that way. If it doesn't work then I'd bet there is something wrong with the data you're receiving.

Comment: It does not work. It may be that the readableStream has not finished reading in (my best guess), do you happen to know of the best practice for waiting on it to finish?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't advise you on that. I would look in to verifying somehow that the base64 is in fact valid base64 (it should end with one or two =, contain no spaces, and only contain a-Z and 0-9). I've had base64 data I sent be sanitized so it's worth looking into. Otherwise I don't know what else to tell ya, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: It is definitely valid bae 64. You helped a lot, and helped me get many attempts quickly on the way.

Now I believe it isjust because of an unfinished stream